# Why combining floating point representation with precision is not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, precision

WHy is below code not giving proper output till requested precision? Please note that since i am using std::fixed so i am expecting precision to be representing digits after decimal points. Hope thats correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double d3 = 50388143.0682372156805328369140625;
    std::cout << "d3 = " << d3 << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(17) << std::fixed << "d3 = " << d3 << std::endl; 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << std::fixed << "d3 = " << d3 << std::endl; 
}
```

Produces output as

```
d3 = 5.03881e+07
d3 = 50388143.06823721528053284   // See its different than original floating point
d3 = 50388143.06823721528053283691 // See its different than original floating point
```

Why isn't the output coming as

```
d3 = 5.03881e+07
d3 = 50388143.06823721568053283
d3 = 50388143.06823721568053283691
```

I was expecting the output digits to match with input digits till requested precision but its not the case. Why so?

Comment: `double` is accurate to about 15 decimal digits. You can't expect it to be more precise than that. Consider: your literal has 33 decimal digits - that's `33/log(2)` or about 109 bits of information. But `sizeof(double) == 64`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Can you explain this a bit more? What do you mean by "accurate to about"? Isn't there a deterministic value? How can  i find out exact value to which it will be accurate? How does 109 bits map to 64 bits and then we get 15?

Comment: There's a finite number of values representable in a `double` (since it consists of a finite number of bits), whereas there's an infinite number of real values. When the compiler parses your long literal, it has to find a value that is closest to the exact mathematical value of that literal among all values representable in a `double`. That approximate value is expected to match the first 15 significant digits of the literal; after that, you observe rounding error.

Comment: See also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - is their any c++ helper macro or something available which can tell me what will be the significant digits upto which the type will be accurate?

Comment: You may be looking for [`std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Perfect. Thanks. I realized there is something like numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10 also there. What's that for now?

Comment: `digits10` is how many decimal digits a floating-point type can represent without loss: for every distinct number consisting of no more than `digits10` decimal digits, there's a distinct floating point value nearest to it. `max_digits10` is the other way round: how many digits do you need to have a distinct decimal value for every representable floating-point value. For `double`, I think `digits10 == 15` and `max_digits10 == 16`

Comment: You asked where the number 15 comes from. On a typical implementation, `double` is 64-bits large, of which 53 bits are used for mantissa (and the rest is the sign bit and exponent). 53 bits can represent `53*lg(2)` or `15.95...` decimal digits.

Answer (score 0):

`d3` does not have the value OP expects.

---

`double` is typically a 64-bit object and so can exactly represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.

50388143.0682372156805328369140625 is **not** one of them.

Typical [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) is encoded as an integer (less than 2<sup>53</sup>) times some power of 2.  See [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational#In_computing).

The closest `double` is `1690745520189437 * pow(2,-25)` or

```
50388143.068237215_2805328369140625   // closest double
50388143.068237215_6805328369140625   // OP's original code.
50388143.068237222_731113433837890625 // next best double
```

Printing `50388143.068237215_2802805328369140625` with `setprecision(17)` is expected to be:

```
50388143.06823721528053284
```

as seen by OP.

Comment: why is your little lower having higher value? And how did 2 change to 6?

Comment: thanks. All understood except this line "The closest double is 1690745520189437 * pow(2,-25)". How is this figure arrived at?

Comment: @Test, One method, keep doubling `50388143.0682372156805328369140625` until it is an integer and still less than 2^53.  Given 25 digit fraciton of .0682372156805328369140625, that takes at least 25 doublings.